# Indexing In ElasticSearch For Auditing

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana, auditing, audit-logging

There is a microservice-based architecture wherein each service has a different type of entity. For example:

Service-1:

```
{
    "entity_type": "SKU",
    "sku": "123",
    "ext_sku": "201",
    "store": "1",
    "product": "abc",
    "timestamp": 1564484862000
}
```

Service-2:

```
{
    "entity_type": "PRODUCT",
    "product": "abc",
    "parent": "xyz",
    "description": "curd",
    "unit_of_measure": "gm",
    "quantity": "200",
    "timestamp": 1564484863000
}
```

Service-3:

```
{
  "entity_type": "PRICE",
  "meta": {
    "store": "1",
    "sku": "123"
  },
  "price": "200",
  "currency": "INR",
  "timestamp": 1564484962000
}
```

Service-4:

```
{
  "entity_type": "INVENTORY",
  "meta": {
    "store": "1",
    "sku": "123"
  },
  "in_stock": true,
  "inventory": 10,
  "timestamp": 1564484864000
}
```

I want to write an **Audit Service** backed by **elasticsearch**, which will ingest all these entities and it will index based on `entity_type`, `store`, `sku`, `timestamp`.

Will elasticsearch be a good choice here? Also, how will the indexing work? So, for example, if I search for `store=1`, it should return all the different entities that have `store` as `1`. Secondly, will I be able to get all the entities between 2 `timestamps`?

Will ES and Kibana (to visualize) be good choices here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your use case is pretty much exactly what is [described in the docs under filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html):

> In filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this
>   document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or
>   No — no scores are calculated. Filter context is mostly used for
>   filtering structured data, e.g.
>
> - Does this timestamp fall into the range 2015 to 2016?
> - Is the status field set to `published`?